# Removing the default DNS servers from ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, linux-networking, ubuntu-20.04

I have an ubuntu 20.04 server and I want to change its DNS settings. The server is using netplan and cloud-init.

I disabled cloud-init network configuraion by creating `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` file with the following content:

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

There is an automatically generated `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` with the following content (I've added the `nameservers` section by myself):

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:d9:e5:96
            mtu: 1458
            set-name: ens3
            addresses: [192.168.0.48/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [178.22.122.100, 185.51.200.2]
```

And Just to make sure nothing overrides these settings, I created a copy of the `50-cloud-init.yaml` file, named `60-change-dns.yaml` in the `/etc/netplan/` directory with the following content:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:d9:e5:96
            mtu: 1458
            set-name: ens3
            addresses: [192.168.0.48/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [178.22.122.100, 185.51.200.2]
```

Then I ran `sudo netplan apply` command and everything seemed to be working fine. To check if the name servers have changed, I executed `sudo resolvectl status` and here is the output (the interesting part):

```
Link 2 (ens3)
      Current Scopes: DNS           
DefaultRoute setting: yes           
       LLMNR setting: yes           
MulticastDNS setting: no            
  DNSOverTLS setting: no            
      DNSSEC setting: no            
    DNSSEC supported: no            
  Current DNS Server: 178.22.122.100
         DNS Servers: 178.22.122.100
                      185.51.200.2  
                      8.8.8.8       
                      8.8.4.4       
          DNS Domain: openstacklocal
```

What the hell are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` in the DNS server list? They were there by default and my purpose was not to add two more DNS servers on top of them. I wanted to completely replace them with my own custom DNS servers.

How do I remove `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` from the DNS server list?

Answer (score 1):

dhcp4: true

change to **dhcp4: false**. It's picking up the Google DNS servers from your DHCP server (probably router), and you have a static ip config.

Comment: I actually managed to solve this problem using `dhcp4-overrides` I needed to disable the DNS provided by the DHCP server